# Copy list structure from SharePoint Online to SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-online, 2010, sharepoint-list

I have one list (**RequestList**) in SharePoint Online.

I have a requirement for which I want to create a replica of this list (**RequestList**)  in SharePoint 2010.

I tried to copy structure of a list from SharePoint Online to SharePoint 2010 using Sharegate but I open the list, I am getting an error as below:

`Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c' or one of its dependencies`

is there any way to copy list structure from SharePoint Online to SharePoint 2010? Or I will have to create this list manually?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

- Save the list in the SP Online as a template
- Download that file to your computer
- import it into the list template gallery for the 2010 site
- add an app in 2010 and choose that template

I do not have a way to test this out with a 2010 environment but this should work for you.

Also, another option would be to export to excel and save and import into 2010 with spreadsheet, of course you will have to go back and fix any non SLOT columns to date/choice etc.